# Toolbar Deleted in Workbook_BeforeClose but Does not Reappear if User Clicks Cancel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a custom toolbar which is created when my workbook is opened and deleted in the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event.  However, if the user then gets prompted to save the file (before closing) and clicks **Cancel**, the file is not closed, but I can't figure out how to automatically re-create the toolbar.

Is there any event which would fire at this point from which I can call the code to create the toolbar?

Comment: Add some code to your handler to check if the workbook needs saving, and if it does then prompt the user whether they want to save it (or Cancel the close).

Answer (score 0):

You have to evalutate the Cancel propery.

If the user clicks cancel then the Cancel propery will be set to true.

You code will look something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
     If Cancel = True Then
         'Do something on cancel
     Else
         'Do something when not cancelled
     End if
End Sub
```

Alternatively you could check only if the Cancel is false and only in that case delete the toolbar.

If this doesn't get you what you need then you can add code to the AfterSave method and checking the Success property.

Comment: `Cancel` is always `False` going into the handler - you can choose whether to set it to `True` in the handler, in which case the close is cancelled and the workbook stays open.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220801(v=office.11).aspx